# How to search for a specific class via beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer
import os
import httplib2
def make_soup(s):
   match=re.compile('https://|http://|www.|.com|.in|.org|gov.in')
   if re.search(match,s):
     http = httplib2.Http()
     status, response = http.request(s)
     page = BeautifulSoup(response,parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
     return page
   else:
     return None

def is_a_valid_link(href):
   match1=re.compile('http://|https://')
   match2=re.compile('/r/WritingPrompts/comments/')
   match3=re.compile('modpost')
   return re.search(match1,href) and re.search(match2,href) and not re.search(match3,href) 
def parse(s):
    c=0
    flag=0
    soup=make_soup(s)
    match4=re.compile('comments')
    if(soup!=None):
        for tag in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'class':['title may-blank loggedin']}):
           #if(link['class']!=['author may-blank loggedin']):
           #if(not re.search(re.compile('/r/WritingPrompts/comments/'),link['href'])):
                  print(tag.string)
                  #break
                  flag=1
                  c=c+1
def count_next_of_current(s):
    soup=make_soup(s)
    match=re.compile('https://www.reddit.com/r/WritingPrompts/?count=')
    for link in soup.find_all('a',{'rel':['next']}):
        href=link['href']
        return href
def read_reddit_images():
    global f
    f=open('spaceporn.txt','w')
    i=int(input('Enter the number of NEXT pages from the front WritingPrompts page that you want to scrape\n'))
    s='https://www.reddit.com/r/WritingPrompts/'
    soup=make_soup(s)
    parse(s)
    count=0
    while(count<i):
        s=count_next_of_current(s)
        if(s!=None):
            parse(s)
            count=count+1
        else:
            break
    f.close()
read_reddit_images()
```

I am trying this code to give me text out of posts. The first step I want is to extract the header text only, then the comments and submitter. I am stuck in the first step. Why can't it find the specific class I mentioned? Isn't that absolutely unique here?

Yes I do know about PRAW but its absolutely frustrating to get it to work. I have read it not-so-well-written documentation twice and there's huge limitation to the number of posts that can be accessed at once. This is not the case with beautifulsoup. Any recommendations relating web scraping in python or in any other language?

Answer (score 0):

Each class attributes stored as individual class in BS4. It is easier to use CSS selector via `select()` method to match by multiple CSS classes. For example, you can use the following CSS selector to match `<a class="title may-blank loggedin">` :

```
for tag in soup.select('a.title.may-blank.loggedin'):
    .....
    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for searching for a class with find_all() is

```
soup.find_all(class_="className")
```

Note the underscore after class. If you leave it out Python will throw you an exception as it thinks you're trying to instantiate a new class.